# I am having a table layout inside a list view

Tags: android

I am having a table view inside list view.

I want to make the table dynamic. There are fixed 3 columns, but the rows vary in number.

There is a image in each cell. I want that there should be as many table cell as number of images. The number of table rows vary in each row of the list view.

When I create table the image is add to the last cell.

```
public class BrandView extends LinearLayout {

    TableLayout table_layout;
     Context context;
     Brand brand;
     CheckBox chkType,chkName;
     TextView txtTypeName,txtBrandName;
     ImageView imgBrandImage;

    public BrandView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context;
        HookUp();
    }

    public void setBrandView( Brand brand){
        this.brand=brand;

        imgBrandImage.setImageResource(brand.getImage());
        txtTypeName.setText(brand.getTypeName());
    }

    public  void HookUp(){
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_brand_select_view,null);
        chkType=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkType);
        txtTypeName=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTypeName);
        table_layout=(TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

        BuildTable(1,1);
        this.addView(view);
    }


     private void BuildTable(int rows, int cols) {


        // outer for loop
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {

            TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(200,
                    200));

            // inner for loop
            for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View tv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_table, null);
                chkName=(CheckBox) tv.findViewById(R.id.chkName);
                txtBrandName=(TextView) tv.findViewById(R.id.txtBrandName);
                imgBrandImage=(ImageView) tv.findViewById(R.id.imgBrandImage);
                row.addView(tv);

                }

                table_layout.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

              /*  if(i==rows)
                    for(int l=k;l>0;l--)
                        row.removeViewAt(l);*/

        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add rows to your `TableView` programatically like you do it in `BuildTable()` method. The point is you need to call this method every time in `ListView`'s adapter `getView()` method.

Comment: i tried calling the BuildTable() method in the adapter but it is still not working.

Comment: Show me how you did it. Also you better move this your method out from View class and it to the adapter class with corresponding modifications. And call from `getView()` passing your TableView to.

Comment: can we create a single table cell instead of row?

Comment: A table cell requires table row (its like a cell), thus you need to add a row and then any other widgets into that row. Then repeat for next cells.

Comment: can you plese give some code on how to add dynamically a table cell to row

Comment: You have it in your `private void BuildTable(int rows, int cols)` method already.